# Why would the login page reload indefinitely?

Tags: login, errors

I tried to log into a blog I administer, after 2+ weeks of no issues, and today I suddenly cannot log in. I have not updated the core or any plugins. The DB hasn't changed, and no significant changes have been made to my system.

I've tried IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, clearing cookies before each, in normal and private browsing modes. I've tried renaming my plugins folder and my theme folder. It's not a password issue. The login page just reloads over and over, and it just started happening out of the blue.

I've run into many posts about this, and disabling plugins or changing settings on config.php seem to be the most common solutions. But none of these have worked for me! Any new suggestions?

**Update** It looks like it's upgraded to 3.5.2 (from 3.5.1) and that may be causing the issues, though I somehow doubt such a small update would cause such a big fuss. Since no one updated it, this leads me to also ask...does WP auto update?

Comment: How do you know it isn't a password issue? Have you [checked the database tables for problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html)?

Comment: If it is a DB issue, I personally cannot look directly. I've tried password resets, and the new ones don't even work.

Comment: If the core was updated (by whom or what?) without you doing it, how do you know there hadn't been more changes? WP does **not** provide automatic core updates natively. Try contacting your hosting support about the issue.

Comment: I def will, because it was in fact updated, and I didn't do it.

Comment: A small versions change usually wouldn't cause problems. My experience is that WordPress updates are very carefully crafted. Also, I have personally never know an update to effect the login system like that. I would guess that more than just WordPress was updated and that the server itself has seen some updates-- PHP, MySQL, Apache, the OS, all of the above, something.

Comment: I just talked to the server admin. He said nothing has changed in the last 48 hours. I manually downgraded to 3.5.1, and it didn't help. I am stumped.

Comment: Back to the damaged tables, then. Or you've been hacked. I think you are going to need DB access, or get help from someone who has it. If the site works, WordPress has DB access so you could write SQL, execute it with `$wpdb` and dump the results to get the information you need. Messy but it should work.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind if the problem persists. I had to have this sorted earlier today, no matter what, so I just had a 2nd DB made and the 1st deleted. All is well now. Much thanks for the information.